# Text exceeding table limit vertically with multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

I would like to adjust the table size vertically so that the text could fit.

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Examples of waterproofing of molded pulp products.}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{lp{7cm}l}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Base material} & \textbf{Additives} & \textbf{Reference}\\
    \midrule
    Recycled paper pulp & Diatomite and bentonite, pore structures with good adsorption performance & \cite{bibid}\\
    Softwood pulp & Low molecular weight and highly cationic coagulant followed by a high molecular weight anionic flocculent. Optimal degrees of grease-proofing and water proofing & \cite{bibid}\\
    Unbleached Kraft pulp & \multirow{2}{7cm}{Palm oil from empty fruit bunch (EFB) and AKD (alkyl ketene dimer). The addition of EFB provided a higher water contact angle, that gave better water resistance properties} & \cite{bibid} \\
    Old newspapers & & \cite{bibid}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\label{table1}%
```

\end{table}%

[image]

Comment: avoid scaling tables `\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}` will give inconsistent font sizes, just use a smaller font such as `\small` or `\footnotesize` whatever fits.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to employ either the `multirow` or the `adjustbox` package. Just use a `tabularx` environment and permit LaTeX to find optimal linebreaks. I suggest you allow linebreaks in both the first and the second column. The code below also arranges for hanging indentation of the second and further lines in each cell.

[image]

I can't help but remark that setting `\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}` makes for, well, rather heavy-looking top- and bottom-rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
    \hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X} % allow hyphenation
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
    \hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}} % allow hyphenation
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Unbleached Kraft} % width of first column
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Examples of waterproofing of molded pulp products.}
\label{table1}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{\mylen} L l @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Base material} & \textbf{Additives} & \textbf{Ref.}\\
    \midrule
    Recycled paper pulp & Diatomite and bentonite, pore structures with good adsorption performance & \cite{bibid}\\
    \addlinespace
    Softwood pulp & Low molecular weight and highly cationic coagulant followed by a high molecular weight anionic flocculent. Optimal degrees of grease-proofing and waterproofing. & \cite{bibid}\\
    \addlinespace
    Unbleached Kraft pulp, old news\-papers & Palm oil from empty fruit bunch (EFB) and AKD (alkyl ketene dimer). The addition of EFB provided a higher water contact angle, that gave better water resistance properties. & \cite{bibid,bibid} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, I forgot to mention that "Old newspapers" should be together with "Unbleached Kraft pulp", but in a new line (as you can see from my attached image). In the same way, ref. should be aligned.
That was why I used multirow. Please advise if you have a solution! Thanks.

Comment: @JhonDoe - Thanks for providing additional information regarding the intended structure of the table. Does the revised answer meet your formatting objectives?

Comment: Almost! "Old newspapers" should be in another line, same as for the ref.